# Hosting WebApi and MVC WebUI in SF

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm looking to migrate my Cloud Services to SF, which include a WebApi (WCF based) and an MVC WebUI (MVC 5.2), as well as a number of worker roles. I've seen a few different sources state the following to be true:

1. You can host WCF WebApi's in SF
2. You can host MVC v5.x WebUI's in SF
3. You can host the above and allow them to share publicly exposed ports 80/443 from a single SF cluster

The worker roles are easy, but I have been unable to find any good docs or blog posts on the specific's of how to accomplish #'s 1-3 above. Can anyone point me at some concrete docs/blogs on these topics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're coming from Worker Roles, this doc can help get you started: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cloud-services-migration-worker-role-stateless-service/

Specifically to your questions:

- WCF web APIs should be possible if you're using WCF self-hosting
- MVC is only supported with ASP.NET Core 1 (this is still fairly new, docs are in-progress, in the meantime, [here is an example](https://github.com/weidazhao/Hosting)).
- Yes, ASP.NET Core 1 allows this if you use WebListener for your web host, which allows you to open listeners either on unique URL paths, or using unique hostnames, all on the same port on a single machine (either in the same process or in multiple processes).

Comment: I see, I guess I was misled about MVC v5.x support in Service Fabric. I'm guessing that is not planned for the future?

Comment: Service Fabric doesn't support IIS, so anything that depends on System.Web from ASP.NET prior to Core 1 isn't going to work. It may be possible however to host IIS inside a container in the future.